# What kind of determinant is this?

Tags: determinant

[image]

*Source: http://www.mathwords.com/a/area_convex_polygon.htm*

What kind of determinant is that? Is there a standard convention to interpret determinants in that form?

Of course, looking at the expansion, one  can guess that the same determinant could be written as a sum of $2\times2$ determinants but the I am concerned about the way it has been represented in the aforementioned website: whether it is a standard practice or not.

Comment: This is not commonly used notation,.  Most people would not call this operation "determinant", as it doesn't satisfy many of the desired properties determinants are expected to have.

Comment: What is that notation called? I was wondering if that website invented a new form of determinant or if such a representation already existed.

Comment: I, personally, have never seen this operation, with any notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is known as the [shoelace formula](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Shoelace_formula).